# Mysql - select a whole row and few fields (in one query)

Tags: mysql, join

### MYSQL

## Select full row and join some fields from few other rows

I have a table like

```
|-----------------------|
|key1|key2|key3|key4|id-|
|1---|2---|3---|4---|1--|
|43--|35--|566-|52--|1--|
|45--|25--|6---|245-|2--|
|45--|25--|608-|24--|2--|
|-----------------------|
```

`key4` is index key which is used to start selection.

i have to get whole row (f.i. 1st row) AND `key3` values for all other rows with the same `id` (1).

So i imagine result for first line like `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 566`

For second row it would be like `43, 35, 566, 52, 1, 3`

Is there any way to do it this way or i really have to make another query?

Comment: In your question, please specify the critiera upon which you use to select the row from which column 3 is used. For example, you want 1,2,3,4,1,566 why did you choose 566 and not 608? The criteria is important. Also, what makes your a row unique?

Comment: I need to find a row with `key4`=4 to get 1st row, and `key3` from the other rows with the same `id` as row with `key4`=4

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself on `id`:

```
select t1.*, group_concat(t2.key3) other_key3
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.id = t1.id
  and t1.key3 != t2.key3
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3738c/2) of this query running over your data

The extra condition of key3 being different is required to stop rows from joining to themselves. Note that this would normally be a comparison of row identifiers, but your table doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: there are could be up to 10 rows with same `id`, which is leads to 10x repeating `t1.*` in output. i wonder about appending column per every row with same `id`

Comment: OK. Sorted out the "many other rows" issue. See new query (and link)